# Why is my Mocha/Chai test giving a false positive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

As a pre-cursor to this question, I am a novice at Node, JS, Mocha and Chai!

I have a set of tests which I run using npm run start, in which 'start' defines a script within my Package.json file:

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "cli-color": "^1.1.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.16.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "superagent": "^3.3.2"
  }
```

Here is my test:

```js
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const screenshotFolder = 'puppeteer/test/screenshots';

module.exports = async(page) => {

  const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.name() === 'iframe');

  const allChoicesButton = await frame.$('.statement a.all-choices');
  await allChoicesButton.click({});

 
    const saveYourChoicesButton = await frame.$('.button.permissions-block__submit');
    await saveYourChoicesButton.click({});

 try {
    const confirmationMessageText = await frame.$eval('.submission-response__copy > p', e => e.textContent);

    describe('User can choose all', function() {
      it('Click choose all and display a confirmation message', function(done) {
        expect(confirmationMessageText).to.equal('Thank you. Your choices have been updatedx.').
        notify(done)
      });
    });

  } catch (err) {
    await page.screenshot({
      path: screenshotFolder + '/confirmationMessageText.png',
      fullPage: true
    });
  }
};
```

I have purposefully added an 'x' to 'updatedx' so it fails....only it passes.  So, I'm sure this has been asked 100 times but I'm unclear as to why it is passing and also why the screenshot is printed, given that an error is not thrown.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked if `confirmationMessageText` contains what you expect it is?

Answer (score 0):

I've realised the error now, swapped frame.$eval with frame.$ and this has resolved the issue.